# Calculate the average/best Rotation between two coordinate systems

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, least-squares, svd

Through a sensor I get the rotation between points in coordinate system A to points in coordinate system B. The measured rotations between the coordinate systems are not $100\%$ identical due to the noise of the sensor.

How can I determine the average or optimal rotation matrix between the coordinate systems? Similar to this problem: [stackoverflow: Averaging Quatenion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374087/average-of-multiple-quaternions), but contrary to that I do not want to use Quaternions, but try some least square approach.

```
Given: Rba(n): Rotation matrix from a to b, measured at n different time points

Wanted: Rba optimal
```

My approach: Minimization of the squared distance.

First I define $n $random points in space and apply the rotations to these points.

$$\begin{pmatrix} bx(n)\\by(n)\\bz(n) \end{pmatrix}=Rba(n) * \begin{pmatrix} \text{random}_xn\\\text{random}_yn\\\text{random}_zn \end{pmatrix}$$

And now I can calculate the rotation by means of the Krabsch algorithm using singular value decomposition to minimize the square distance between the input points and the transformed points.
However, what I don't understand is that the calculated rotation matrix seems to be dependent on the input points. That is, I get different rotation matrices as a result for different input points, although the applied rotation matrices $Rba(n)$ remain the same.
Why is that? And what is the right way?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the samples not being linearly dependant. However it might not only depend on the samples but also on the number of samples. You would need at least three samples per matrix. However having too many samples might lead to have bad distribution of errors. Since least squares is minimizing the SUM of squared errors, it migth allow to have large errors on a bunch of samples provided that majority of samples are fitted exactly. Resulting on having lower error overall at the expense of high error on few samples. That doesn't happen when number of samples is low.